# How to draw waveform of Android's music player?

Tags: android, audio, waveform, sampling

one of the default live wallpapers that came with my phone was a wallpaper that displayed the wave form of music playing in the background in real time. I was wondering how one could go about doing this. It seems I should somehow access the streaming data of the background music and compute the samples in real time, but I have no idea how to get the streaming data. I think I can display the wave form by following this tutorial http://codeidol.com/java/swing/Audio/Build-an-Audio-Waveform-Display/, but I'm not exactly sure how to do it. Help would be greatly appreciated/

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is an Android class called Visualizer that lets you access audio being played
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/Visualizer.html

In addition, since Android is all open source, you can look at how the live wallpaper does it!
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/wallpapers/MusicVisualization/

Comment: Is there an updated link to that last one?

Comment: Found it here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/wallpapers/MusicVisualization/