# android: Best way to draw on an ImageView?

Tags: android, imageview, surfaceview

I am creating an app, which has an audio player. I get the audio file, and the image file (the waveform of the audio) from a server. I want to draw on the waveform, and I am here for advice, which are the best solution.

1, I want to give the opportunity to the user to highlight an interval on the waveform. It would be great if I could handle multitouch.
What widget should I use for better performance? Should I use surfacelayout or what do you recommend? I dont really hav any experience in this field.

Answer (score 0):

The following links might be of help:

[How to draw waveform of Android's music player?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6317842/how-to-draw-waveform-of-androids-music-player)

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/media/AudioFxDemo.html