# How to make Custom Media Visualizer in android?

Tags: android, animation, media-player

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to draw waveform of Android’s music player?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6317842/how-to-draw-waveform-of-androids-music-player)

Right Now i am in trouble. i want to make custom media player skin. just like windows player in that so many different theme can be apply . i need one of them like waveform . i find out on web but they just help about simpal ui skin . like previous next pause button . i found one of [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjzoa.jpg) ,

**How it should be looks ?**

[image]

Actually i **just need only a blue skin of wave** out of whole image . other thing is optional.

So ,Please Guide me what i have to do for implement this. is there need of animation to complete this task ?

Any Guidance or suggestion should be appreciated.

Comment: Please ,once you should tell me where is my problem ? either my Question is wrong but concept is write .so you people at least reply me with  any positive or negative response. Do not give down vote. Thanks for Help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is not a skin, but a visualizer UI. Take a look at [`Visualizer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/Visualizer.html) for information on how to "*retrieve part of the currently playing audio for visualization purpose*".

Comment: Thanks Buudy. can you show me any demo example for it.?

Comment: [Google](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=android+visualizer) is your friend.

Comment: ya i found one example . just checking it .Thanks to get me a right direction. my question is wrong but my concept is write. thanks again